# GeoServer To Vue2-leaflet projection issue

Tags: geoserver, leaflet

I am using GeoServer (using Tomcat in localhost) and to send a WMS file to my Vue2-leaflet application.

My projection in GeoServer is ESPG 4326

This is my Leaflet code :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div style="height: 15%; overflow: auto;">
      <h3>WMS Layers with Layer selector</h3>
      <p>
        <b>NOTE:</b> Use layer symbol on the top right to select which layer you
        want to display. More information about WMS (Web Map Service) can be
        found on the
        <a
          href="http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html"
        >leaflet.js WMS example page</a>.
      </p>
    </div>
    <l-map
      :zoom="zoom"
      :center="center"
      style="height: 80%"
    >
      <l-control-layers />
      <l-wms-tile-layer
        v-for="layer in layers"
        :key="layer.name"
        :base-url="baseUrl"
        :layers="layer.layers"
        :visible="layer.visible"
        :name="layer.name"
        layer-type="base"
      />
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { LMap, LWMSTileLayer, LControlLayers } from "vue2-leaflet";
export default {
  name: "WmsLayers",
  components: {
    LMap,
    "l-wms-tile-layer": LWMSTileLayer,
    LControlLayers
  },
  data() {
    return {
      zoom: 4,
      center: [49, 12],
      url: "http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      baseUrl: "http://localhost:8081/geoserver/cite/wms",
      layers: [
        {
          name: "vnm_polbnda_adm3_2014_pdc",
          visible: true,
          layers: "vnm_polbnda_adm3_2014_pdc"
        },
        {
          name: "Countries",
          visible: false,
          layers: "cite:transacthcmgis_salesaggregated"
        },
        {
          name: "Boundaries and Countries",
          visible: false,
          layers:
            "cite:vnm_polbnda_adm3_2014_pdc"
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

It seems that I have a projection problem when I am rendering into my browser:

[image]
How I can fix this?

Comment: Please use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, we need to know what the exact URLs making the WMS requests are - look in the network debug console of your browser.

Comment: Leaflet by default uses EPSG 3857. If your WMS service returns data in  ESPG 4326, you get what you see in your case. Since Leaflet supports only one CRS per map, you have to change either CRS of your base layer or CRS of WMS layer.